# VBA Userform not populated when opened first time, but works the second time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on Excel and making use of a userform. The idea is to highlight a row, then click a button which opens my useform. Column 10 of the active row consists of comments. I have coded the button so that when it is clicked, the textbox is automatically populated with the contents from column 10. The user can then add to these current comments and then press submit to make the changes.

The problem is that when the button is pressed the first time, the useform will not come populated with the comments. If I exit and do the procuedre again, then it works. What have I done wrong? The code for the button is below (textbox is called 'comment'):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Now")
    UserForm1.Show
    'Add current comments to box
    UserForm1.Comment.Value = ws1.Cells(ActiveCell.row, 10).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell` might be the culprit here. Why don't us use direct reference?

Comment: Note: Here at SO, you should not add "(Solved)"  to your title when your question is answered, but rather just Accept the correct answer (it's the big check mark) and the SO server will flag things appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rearranging your code to be like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Now")
'Add current comments to box
UserForm1.comment.Value = ws1.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 10).Value
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

This should load the data into the text box before it is shown to you.

Comment: Spot on! That makes sense as well. Ask it to do everything before and then show the form. Thank you for your effort. I will also edit the code to fix the typo